# Mounting 2 external drives always in the same way in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, mount

I would mount on Debian (on raspberrypi with nextcloudpi) two external USB drives always in the same sequence (sda, sdb etc..)

Now i've attached one USB External Drive and Debian automap as

```
/media/039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415   /dev/sda1   ext4    rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

and there's a mount point called USBdrive but in the /etc/fstab there's no trace of this mount point (where is written this mount point i don't know)

This is fstab file

```
PARTUUID=037e0064-01  /boot  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=037e0064-02  /ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

If i use

```
ls /media/USBdrive
```

i can see the folders contained in.

The command

```
ls /media/
```

shows me

```
039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415  USBdrive
```

039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415 as shown in dark blue

USBdrive as shown in light blue color

If i connect also the second external USB drive, the USBdrive (mount point) is not accessible because external USB drive has mounted as /dev/sdb1 and not /dev/sda1.

Anyway, i can't find where's written USBdrive mount point because my goal is to edit /etc/fstab and mapping two external USB drive in correct sequence.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a FAQ. The thing to do is **not** to use the kernel assigned names `/dev/sd*` (because they are essentially random), but instead use the symlinks that are provided through udev in `/dev/by-*` in `fstab`.

You can use the UUID, or something else, or give volume labels, it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll want to read the documentation of `[udisks]`[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udisks). In short,  when you insert a USB drive it is read by the system and the appropriate entries are added in the `/dev/` file system. When you access it from a file manager it is automagically mounted under `/media/` using `udisksctl mount`; the mount point is the device's `[UUID]`[2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Persistent_block_device_naming#by-uuid).

This is the "dynamic" way. If you want a more "static" behavior, you could add them in `/etc/fstab` preferably using their respective `UUID`s. This way the mount points will be depended on their unique UUIDs and not on a random `sdx` enumeration they will get.

Comment: I added this line to fstab: `#PARTUUID=039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415 /media/039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0` but system locked because debian give me error (lost dependency) and i can't log in. Other info is: nextcloudpi has datadir variable is set to /media/039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415/ncdata. I lost something.

Comment: You can add the `nofail` option to the `fstab` line so it will not wait for 5min or so to mount the drive. BTW, you don't need to have such an arcane name for the mount point, you could mount it on `/media/disk1`, but in any case you have to create the mount points with `mkdir /media/disk1` or `mkdir /media/039256f6-3ba5-424f-b781-4d14a8746415`, in your case.